# What does it mean for a protein to be dominant-negative?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

I am reading this [journal paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6704904/), which investigates the interaction of the NCAM protein and the Pak1 protein. In this paper I have come across the term "dominant-negative Pak1" and "constitutively active Pak1". I am not sure what exactly is meant by a protein being dominant-negative. I have searched online and found that dominant negative refers to a mutation whose gene product adversely affects the normal wild-type gene product within the same cell (with this occurring if the product can still interact with the same elements as the wild-type product, but block some aspect of its function).

Would I be correct in inferring that dominant-negative Pak1 is a mutated version of the wild-type Pak1 and interferes with the normal activity of wild-type Pak1 in cells? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You've got it. A DN not only doesn't have the desired catalytic activity, but it also binds to or otherwise inactivates WT enzymes, in effect "knocking out" that particular enzyme in the cells. The protein itself is still there, it just doesn't perform its normal function.